# Is there any word for the the feeling/act when the food is so tasty that you close your eyes and chew it slowly?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, food

I'm just looking for a word by which one can explain the moment / feeling / act of closing your eyes and chewing your food slowly with taking enjoying every part of your food.

I'm looking for a noun, but any word adjective/adverb that can replace this long sentence is fine.

Comment: No, but it happens everytime  I come off a low-carb diet.

Comment: Does it really have to be one word? Are you looking for a verb or an adjective?

Comment: You should be able to comment on your own question. Click where it says "add comment", in red, beneath your question.

Comment: Click here https://english.stackexchange.com/contact and select "*I need to merge user profiles*" from the drop down menu.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking specifically for a noun. Consider using the gerund form of the verb *savour*: *savouring*.

Alternately, as you also admit phrases, consider [Mari-Lou's delicious suggestion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440261/is-there-any-word-for-the-the-feeling-act-when-the-food-is-so-tasty-that-you-clo/440266?noredirect=1#comment1056821_440266): *savour every bite*.

> **savour** *verb*
>   with object Taste (good food or drink) and enjoy it completely.
>   ‘gourmets will want to savor our game specialties’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/savor)

Comment: I'm upvoting but I think you should also add "savour every bite" It's three words but replaces that long sentence quite well.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Mmm, *buon appetito*.

Answer (score 2):

**degust**, according to [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/degust)

> VERB Taste (something) carefully to appreciate it fully.

Example sentence from the same source:

> ‘Dennis didn't drink it, he degusted it’

Attribution: "Degust | Definition of Degust in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed April 16, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/degust.

Comment: There's also a noun form of this word: [degustation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degustation).

Comment: This suggestion is degusting.

Answer (score 0):

**relish**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/relish) or the idiom **with relish**

> a. Hearty enjoyment or appreciation:  b. Something that lends pleasure
>   or zest c. A keen liking for something: